# Autumn Harvest Mounts

Tags: rift

A couple days ago in Rift it was announced that the mount quest that is currently going on for the Autumn Harvest event was disabled. I've continued gathering Autumn Harvest Signets in the hopes that by the time I reach the 20 signets needed to purchase a mount the problem will be fixed. After the server merge that occurred yesterday however, I haven't heard anything about the Autumn Harvest in the official forums.

Would anyone happen to know if it is safe to go ahead and try purchasing one of the mounts once you reach 20 signets? I want to know prior to reaching the 20 signets myself since I still see the quest as being active on my quest log.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you already figured out but you should be able to buy the mount for signets directly from RIFT store.